# How to add optional parameters to WKT geometry in openlayers

Tags: openlayers

I want to add some parameters to my WKT point, like 'name', 'population' and 'rainfall'.
The additional features are missing in my map.

```
           // basic map
          .
          .
          .


          // add wkt point


            const wkt = 'POINT (8 50)';

            const format = new ol.format.WKT();

            const iconFeature = format.readFeature(wkt, {
              dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
              featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
              name: 'Aachen',
              population: 220000,
              rainfall: 500
            });
            console.log(iconFeature);

            map.addFeature(iconFeature);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `iconFeature` is an `ol.Feature` you can set any property you want:

```
const iconFeature = format.readFeature(wkt, {
      dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
      featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
    });
iconFeature.set('name', 'Aachen');
iconFeature.set('population', '220000');
iconFeature.set('rainfall', '500');
```

See http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Feature.html and http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.format.WKT.html